# Reverse routing from regex

Tags: php, regex, codeigniter, routes, url-routing

You knows that reverse routing known issue. I'm using CodeIgniter and trying to generate url from regex routes.

My sample route:

```
$route['product-detail/([a-z]+)/(\d+)'] = "catalog/product_view/$2";
```

or:

```
$route['product-detail/([a-z]+)/(\d+)'] = array('catalog/product_view/$2', 'product-detail');
```

Sample usage:

```
<a href="<?php echo route('product-detail' , array('category' => 'bikes', 'id' => 9)); ?>">Item Name</a>
```

Expected output:

```
<a href="/product-detail/bikes/9">Item Name</a>
```

I tried [Easy Reverse Routing](http://codefury.net/2010/09/easy-reverse-routing-with-codeigniter/) but it supports only keys not regex strings.

How can i achive this issue?

Comment: Is the `route()` function part of the stock codeigniter ?

Comment: @Brewal No, just a example non exist function that convert route to url.

Comment: Indeed, the child class that you linked does not seems to be finished. It partly supports regex. You might not see the error "No reverse route found for 'product-detail'" do you ?

Comment: I want to use like `$route['product-detail/([a-z]+)/(\d+)']` instead of `$route['product-detail/(:category)/(:id)']`

Comment: I understood that... I'm working on a fix of the class you linked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this fix for the `reverseRoute` method. Change this :

```
$route = $this->_reverseRoutes[$route_name];

foreach($args_keyval as $key => $val)
{
    $route = str_replace("(:$key)", $val, $route);
}

return $route;
```

to this : **[demo](http://phpad.org/1849275372)**

```
$route = $this->_reverseRoutes[$route_name];

preg_match_all('/\(([^)]+)\)/', $route, $matches);

if (isset($matches[1]) && is_array($matches[1])) {
    $wildCardsAndRegex = $matches[1];
    $index = 0;

    foreach ($args_keyval as $key => $val)
    {
        if (isset($wildCardsAndRegex[$index])) {
            if ($wildCardsAndRegex[$index][0] === ':') {
                // for wildcard
                $route = str_replace('(:'.$key.')', $val, $route);
            } elseif (preg_match('/'.$wildCardsAndRegex[$index].'/', $val)) {
                // for regex
                $route = preg_replace('/\('.preg_quote($wildCardsAndRegex[$index], '\\').'\)/', $val, $route, 1);
            }
        }
        $index++;
    }
}

return $route;
```

Comment: I stacked about optional regex. `$route['products(/[a-z]+)?'] = array('products$1', 'products');` How can i pass optional param? If param exists url should be `products/bikes`, if param not exists, url should be like only `products`.